# Need install Ubuntu Desktop on lenovo B460e model with Window 7 OS

Tags: system-installation

I am beginner to Ubuntu Linux, I want to install Ubuntu desktop OS for learning purpose.

kindly advise me to install Ubuntu OS on my System.

Anything need to know about system property kindly revert me.

Regards,
Mohamed Saleem,

Comment: Where it's for learning, you might prefer to run Ubuntu in a virtual machine running on Windows, using e.g. VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a bootable usb stick or DVD (with an Ubuntu iso image), you can always try it before you install it.

It's good to have a backup of your disk before installing, just in case something goes wrong.

The installation process should be easy. Here is one example:
https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0

Just pay attention to the partitioning section (In the given link, this is section 6:Allocating drive space). Your Windows partitions should be detected. Do **NOT** press Erase disk and install Ubuntu.